# Learning Objective-C: Need advice on populating NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I am teaching myself Objective-C utilizing a number of resources, one of which is the Stanford iPhone Dev class available via iTunes U (past 2010 class).

One of the home work assignments asked that I populate a mutable dictionary with a predefined list of keys and values (URLs). I was able to put the code together, but as I look at it, I keep thinking there is probably a much better way for me to approach what I'm trying to do:

1. Populate a NSMutableDictionary with the predefined keys and values
2. Enumerate through the keys of the dictionary and check each key to see if it starts with "Stanford"
3. If it meets the criteria, log both the key and the value

I would really appreciate any feedback on how I might improve on what I've put together. I'm the very definition of a beginner, but I'm really enjoying the challenge of learning Objective-C.

```
void bookmarkDictionary () {
    NSMutableDictionary* bookmarks = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSString* one = @"Stanford University",
    *two = @"Apple",
    *three = @"CS193P",
    *four = @"Stanford on iTunes U",
    *five = @"Stanford Mall";

    NSString* urlOne = @"http://www.stanford.edu",
    *urlTwo = @"http://www.apple.com",
    *urlThree = @"http://cs193p.stanford.edu",
    *urlFour = @"http://itunes.stanford.edu",
    *urlFive = @"http://stanfordshop.com";

    NSURL* oneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlOne];
    NSURL* twoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlTwo];
    NSURL* threeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlThree];
    NSURL* fourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlFour];
    NSURL* fiveURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlFive];

    [bookmarks setObject:oneURL forKey:one];
    [bookmarks setObject:twoURL forKey:two];
    [bookmarks setObject:threeURL forKey:three];
    [bookmarks setObject:fourURL forKey:four];
    [bookmarks setObject:fiveURL forKey:five];

    NSString* akey;
    NSString* testString = @"Stanford";

    for (akey in bookmarks) {

        if ([akey hasPrefix:testString]) {
            NSLog(@"Key: %@     URL: %@", akey, [bookmarks objectForKey:akey]);
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code appears correct and you are right to think there is a better way. You can reduce the number of temporary variables, and use a (non-mutable) `NSDictionary` instead of a `NSMutableDictionary` by choosing an initializer for the task:

```
NSDictionary *bookmarks = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.stanford.edu"], @"Stanford University",
                             [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"], @"Apple",
                             //...etc...,
                             nil
                          ];
```

Note that `-[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]`, like all Cocoa factory methods, creates an instance that is `autoreleased`. If you intend to keep an ownership of the dictionary past the current scope, you should `retain` the returned instance, or use `alloc/initWithObjectsAndKeys:`.

If the assignment (oddly) requires a mutable dictionary instead, you can of course use `+[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]`.

I happen to prefer the more explicit form of the search that you use. Some may feel that (if you're on 10.6), using a more functional form is better:

```
[bookmarks enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
        if([key hasPrefix:testString]) { NSLog(@"Key: %@  URL: %@", key, value); }
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend the use of a plist for static data (which it appears you have).  If you define a plist, you can then load it directly into an NSDictionary with very little code.

You can read about it here [Plist to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343121/plist-array-to-nsdictionary)