# iOS app - separation of code and content with various elements

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, uiwebview

I am new to iOS app development. I have been reading the documentation on the Apple Developer website as well as reading references on the Internet and I still can't seem to find anything that explains how to separate content from the app such that the content itself is easy to update. The open source iOS examples I have seen all hardcode content into implementation files. Although I have read up on Core Data, I'm not sure if that is the most approriate framework to use for my use case. I want to make a basic app that simply contains lots of views with each view containing various types of UI elements as those seen in HTML for example H1, H2, H3, P, UL and IMG. With Core Data, I'm assuming I would have to somehow save my data(content) into a SQLite database file and then get the app to read it, would this not be tedious? How would I then update the SQLite database in addition to populating it in the first place?

To reiterate I simply want to know, what's the best way to achieve this and still be able to update content relatively easy without having to go to a file that has the content hardcoded.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easier way is to fit them inside plist files, then read them as NSDictionaries 
please read [Plist Array to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343121/plist-array-to-nsdictionary)
and [Parse Plist (NSString) into NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072308/parse-plist-nsstring-into-nsdictionary) for more information

Comment: You are most welcome :) dont forget to accept if it really helped you :)

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot to accept, have now accepted it! Have a nice day!