# Swift: How to get first string of array in plist?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

I have a plist that is an array containing hundreds of arrays, each containing 22 strings. How do I get the first string of each array in the plist?

I'm using collections and in `cellForItemAt` I'm trying to get the first string of the arrays to show under each cell in a label.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Collections

    // Set Image
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: "image_\(indexPath.row)")

    // Check NameLabel Switch Status
    if savedSwitchStatus == true {

        cell.labelCell.isHidden = false
        cell.labelCell.text = (??) // <--------------

    } else {
        cell.labelCell.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have 2 types of plists:

First plist has 1 array with multiple strings. Each string is a name that goes under the cells.
[image: plist1]

Second plist is an array of arrays, each array containing 22 strings. Here I need to get only the first string from each array to show under the cells.
[image: plist2]
[image: plist2_1]

Comment: Just need to get data from plist file and do whatever you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343121/plist-array-to-nsdictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your plist into Array of Array of Strings i.e. [[String]].

```
func arrayFromPlist(plist:String) -> [[String]]? {
    guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: plist, withExtension: "plist"), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl) else {
        return nil
    }

    return try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [[String]]
}
```

Use above function to get the array and use the array as a datasource to tableview.

```
var datasourceArray:[[String]] {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In your cellForRow:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Collections

    // Set Image
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: "image_\(indexPath.row)")
    let strings = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]!
    // Check NameLabel Switch Status
    if savedSwitchStatus == true {

        cell.labelCell.isHidden = false
        cell.labelCell.text = strings.first

    } else {
        cell.labelCell.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used `indexPath.row` on the array of the plist and matched it.